# How to cover a div with an article, until mouseover to show the div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want a nice sliding animation on an article to show a div with more information upon mouseover. A very very similar example is from http://javascriptissexy.com/ when you click at the top right corner the "Show Modern Dev Ad"

This is my code:

```
<style>

.download:hover {
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:40%;
background-color:#DDD;
}

.download {
margin:50px 25%;
height:360px;
background-color:#FFF;
}

.download:hover > div {
visibility:visible;
margin:50px 25%;
height:360px;
position:absolute;
}

.download > div {
background-color:white;
visibility:hidden; /*Only for editing purposes*/
}

</style>
```

```
<section>

    <article class="download">
        <h2>Pong Alpha</h2>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>It's fun</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </article>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").hover(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

I think this is what u are searching for.

Try the example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45jxu/)

Or with mouseover mouseout on your example. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q653B/)

Comment: Or you can do a `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/v25W7/1/), which might be more of what you want

Comment: Or... http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/v25W7/7/ this. This makes it so the panel closes when you mouse out of either the original panel or the slide-down panel (that way a user can click something on the slide-down panel).